# How to group by unique user ID and sort by latest messages ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

my message table

```
message_id | message_body_content | sender_user_id | receiver_user_id
1          | hello world          | 1000           | 1200
2          | hello world 2        | 1001           | 1200
3          | hello world again    | 1000           | 1200
4          | xyz                  | 1001           | 1200
5          | abc                  | 1200           | 1999
```

I want to group by my `message` table by `sender_user_id` unique and by last `message_id`

so output should be like;

```
message_id | message_body_content | sender_user_id | receiver_user_id
3          | hello world again    | 1000           | 1200
4          | xyz                  | 1001           | 1200
```

Because latest `message_id` for `sender_user_id` IS 3. This is in theory.

When I try

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE receiver_user_id = 1200 
GROUP BY sender_user_id
ORDER BY message_id DESC
```

It did not work. Because MySQL grouping first by `message_id` (min message_id value)

then sorting.

How can I get unique sender message by max `message_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to "group".  You want to filter.  So, I think you want:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE m.receiver_user_id = 1200 AND
      m.message_id = (SELECT MAX(m2.message_d)
                      FROM message m2
                      WHERE m2.receiver_user_id = m.receiver_user_id AND
                            m2.sender_user_id = m.sender_user_id 
                     )
ORDER BY m.message_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select message_id, message_body_content, sender_user_id, receiver_user_id
from message t
where t.message_id = (select max(t1.message_id)
                      from message t1
                      where t1.sender_user_id = t.sender_user_id
                     )
order by message_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-query

```
select m.* from message m
where (m.message_id,m.sender_user_id) in(
SELECT max(message_id) as message_id ,sender_user_id
 FROM message  
GROUP BY sender_user_id
 ) and m.receiver_user_id = 1200
ORDER BY m.message_id DESC
```